# How to integrate jenkins with mean stack application

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, mean-stack

I have a Mean stack application and i want to add jenkins CI to it. I am not sure as to how to achieve this. I am using **bower** to install front end packages and **npm** for other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins CI might perform builds which would run tests on mean.
Currntly mean has two types of tests mocha and karma to test the node.js and the angular parts of mean.
You can run them both by running "grunt test"
I've came across these two articles that might help you out
mocha: http://johnhamelink.com/testing-nodejs-with-jenkins.html
karma: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/plus/jenkins.html

Good luck with the intergation